# How can we get val from keyup in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, keyup

i want give val from keyup in jquery

my code is :

```
var vartest;

$( ".target" ).keyup(function() {
  vartest= this.value;
console.log('in func:' + vartest);
});


console.log('out of func:' + vartest);
```

but vartest is undefined

Comment: Its work. See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/o6m7qb5z/).

Comment: see update code

Comment: no , not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function triggers only once your Element receives an event.
At the time you were calling `vartest` (outside of your function) its value is still `undefined` because the event (that actually attaches a value) will trigger at a later time.

Create a function `getTargetsValues` and call that function when needed.
Instead of `"keyup"` you *might eventually* listen for the `"input"` event:

```js
// Cache your elements
const $targets = $(".target");

// Use this function to get an Array of inputs .target values
function getTargetsValues () {
  return $targets.get().map(el => el.value);
}

$targets.on("input", function() {
  console.log('in func: ' + getTargetsValues());
});

console.log('out of func: ' + getTargetsValues());
```

```html
<input class="target" type="text" value="1. target">

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure if this is what you need, but if you want to get value of input where event happened, you should take it from event target:

```
$(‘.target’).keyup(e => {
    vartest = e.target.value;
});
```